# Netbeans + maven + aspectj compile time weaving

Tags: maven-2, aspectj, netbeans-7, compile-time-weaving

I've got a Maven project set-up for compile-time weaving with aspectj (mainly for the @Configurable annotation). Everything works fine with a full build but Netbeans has this feature, like many other IDEs, that does recompiling and hot deployment "on the fly". When it does that, it no longer weaves in the aspects so I get all sorts of NPEs. What's the solution?

Comment: Doesn't NetBeans have an option to run a Maven target on build?

Comment: It has an option for "deploy on save" and you can set a goal for the "Run via deploy" action - which is by default [package]. I don't know if it's a relation between the two of them because my CTW is already linked with the compile phase.

Comment: Not sure if this information will help anybody, but it looks like there is a Netbeans plugin which helps with this issue, but it hasn't been updated to work with Netbeans 7 :( 
http://www.jroller.com/ramlog/entry/features